# PL/SQL Developer test script fails in execute mode and passes in debug mode

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, testing, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a test script(.tst) file which I run in PL/SQL Developer.

When I run the test in non debug mode(By pressing F8), it fails because some fields hadn't been updated when a certain Assert statement runs.

But when I run it in debug mode (By pressing F9 then Ctrl+R) it runs successfully and all fields have the correct value at the check points(Assert statements).

Has anyone any idea why this can happen? It really drives me crazy. It might be something related to parallelism or something else that I am not aware of.

Comment: Seems some hard coded values are getting passed to your code when you run in test mode. Check if you don't pass anything while running your code in test mode.

Comment: @XING thanks for considering my question. I doubt that we pass any thing based on debug mode. At least when I search for **$$debug_mode** I can not find anything in the source codes. Although I will investigate more about this.

Comment: `$$debug_mode` must be something defined at environment level. Check that as well.

Comment: @XING Just a side question. Do you know how can we run .tst files from command prompt? I tried different ways with SQLPLUS command line tool but it wasn't possible.

Comment: Did you try this this way: First connect to sqlplus using your username/password. Then run as `@<path of your script>scriptname` for eg. `@ anc/fnnd/.tst`

Comment: @XING Before it was complaining about the header : **PL/SQL Developer Test script 3.0**
After I manually removed the header yes it runs it. I should search for this pattern to see if we use this to run the test scripts.

Comment: It's not just the header line. PL/SQL Developer's `.tst` file format include line counts, bind variable definitions and various state details. It can't be run in any other tool - you would need to copy the code into another script.